Lower Bound for eigenvalue of a special form of symmetric tridiagonal matrix
Given the special tridiagonal matrix, where all constant $c_i >1$ and can be arbitrary large.
\begin{equation}
    V^\top V = \begin{bmatrix}
        2c_1^2 & -c_1 c_2 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\
        -c_1 c_2 & 2c_2^2 & -c_2 c_3 & \cdots & 0  & 0\\
        0 & -c_2 c_3 & 2c_3^2 & \cdots & 0  & 0\\
        \vdots & \vdots& \vdots& \ddots& \vdots  & \vdots\\
        \vdots & \vdots& \vdots& \ddots& \vdots  & \vdots\\
        0 & 0 & 0&   \cdots &  2 c_{n-1}^2 & -c_{n-1} c_{n}  \\
        0 & 0 & 0&   \cdots &  -c_{n-1} c_{n} & 2c_{n}^2
    \end{bmatrix}
    \in \mathbb R^{n \times n},
\end{equation}
I wonder if there is any lower bound for the minimum eigenvalue of this matrix, independently on parameters $c_i$. My guess is the lower bound of order $1/n^2$, but i cannot find a way to show it.
The reason my guessing is $\Theta(1/n^2)$ is that, if all $c_i = 1$, then we have Toeplitz matrix, and the closed form eigenvalue is
$2 + 2\cos\left(\frac{(n-1)\pi}{n}\right) \sim \frac{4}{n^2}$.
Many thanks in advance!!

NB: In the toeplitz case, the minimum eigenvalue is $ \min_{k \leq n} 4 c^2 \sin^2(k \pi/(n+1)) = 4c^2  \sin^2(\pi/(n+1)) \asymp \tfrac{c^2}{(n+1)^2}$.

Note that, defining $c_{n+1} = 0$,we have
$$
\langle V x, Vx \rangle = 
\sum_{j=1}^n (c_j x_j - c_{j+1} x_{j+1})^2 + c_j^2 x_j^2 - c_{j+1}^2 x_{j+1}^2
= 
c_1^2x_1^2 + \sum_{j = 1}^n (c_j x_j - c_{j+1} x_{j+1})^2.
$$
Let $y = Cx$ correspond to $y_i = c_i x_i$. Note that $\langle Vx, Vx \rangle = \langle L y, L y\rangle$, where $L^TL$ is the symmetric tridiagonal matrix with $c_i = 1$.
Then,
$$
x^T V^T V x = x^T C^T L^T L C x \geq \lambda_{\rm min}(L^T L) \|Cx\|_2^2 \geq \lambda_{\rm min}(L^TL) (\min_{i} c_i^2) \|x\|_2^2.  
$$
But, as you note, $\lambda_{\rm min}(L^TL) \asymp n^{-2}$, so from here we see that $\lambda_{\rm min}(V^T V) \asymp c^2n^{-2}$.

Ah, I did not know the answer could be that straightforward. Thanks a lottt!
